# C++ NetBeans "Identifier whose declaration cannot be found." Error

Tags: c++, netbeans

The screenshot shows a bunch of variable declarations in C++ on NetBeans IDE and each one has the error "Identifier whose declaration cannot be found.":

[image: The screenshot shows a bunch of variable declarations in C++ on NetBeans IDE and each one has the error "Identifier whose declaration cannot be found.".]

I've looked at a few other posts on the topic already and the solutions that seem to work for others aren't helping. It may be something simple (such as missing a symbol somewhere) or I'm doing this completely wrong. I'm currently learning C++, I did fine with Java and Python with NetBean, no problem. But I'm getting a ton of errors with this code.

this is the sample code below. (Its not nearly finished but not sure why this error is on every line so far)

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cctype>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
/*
 * 
 */
int main() {
    int mazeMap[4][4] = {
        {32, 34, 3, 32, 34}
        {13, 13, 12, 14, 13}
        {1, 12, 24, 24, 14}
        {3, 12, 234, 24, 34}
        {12, 24, 124, 4, 3}
    };
    int downOrRight = 32;
    int downOrLeft = 34;
    int downOnly = 3;
    int downOrUp = 13;
    int UpOrRight = 12;
    int leftOrUp = 14;
    int upOnly = 1;
    int leftOrRight = 24;
    int downOrLeftOrRight = 234;
    int leftOrDownOrRight = 124;
    int leftOnly = 4;
    
    char northDir = 'w';
    char eastDir = 'd';
    char southDir = 's';
    char westDir = 'a';
    cout << "Welcome to the Marble Maze" << endl;
    while (userInp != 'q') {
        
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I do not use netbeans, but there are several issues with the code.
The maze map array is too small. You would need to dimension it to `[5][5]` for the values you have given. Also the initialization lists need commas between them:

```
int mazeMap[5][5] = {
    {32, 34, 3, 32, 34},
    {13, 13, 12, 14, 13},
    {1, 12, 24, 24, 14},
    {3, 12, 234, 24, 34},
    {12, 24, 124, 4, 3}
};
```

The variable `userInp` is not declared.
Also running the program will end in an endless loop. So you might want to add code for the user input.

Comment: Oh alright, I had just used NetBeans for Java so I thought it would be easier. Thank you for the help!

Comment: When you found the answer helpful, please consider accepting it.